# How to diff files ignoring specific words?

Tags: linux, regular-expression, diff

I have two Files 
test1:

```
[BEFORE_TEST] WARN: message1
[BEFORE_TEST] NOTICE: message
```

test2:

```
[AFTER_TEST]  PASS: message1
[AFTER_TEST]  NOTICE: message
```

test2 is the fixes that i made based on test1, now i want to use diff to show the differences ignoring [BEFORE_TEST] and [AFTER_TEST] in both files. Problem is NOTICE is being considered for "difference" due to change in tags from [BEFORE_TEST] to [AFTER_TEST]. Is there any way we can ignore these specific words?

Comment: diff test1 test2 | grep -v [BEFORE_TEST]||[AFTER_TEST]?

Comment: Ignoring the tags may be insufficient. There is one space character before `NOTICE`, then a trailing space after `message` in `test1`, but respectively two space characters and no trailing space in `test2`. Is this just clumsiness of the question? Or is this a real thing and you want solutions that ignore such differences as well?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you need to eliminate those parts through removing them while searching differences:

```
wdiff <(sed 's/^\[[^]]\+\] *//' test1) <(sed 's/^\[[^]]\+\] *//' test2)
```

The output:

```
[-WARN:-]{+PASS:+} message
```